# How to use rgb value to add color in pandas.scatter_matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I want to add color in `pd.scatter_matrix`, the rgb value like that,

```
   val_rgb = [[127  80  34]
     [130  89  34]
     [170 133  75]
     ...]
```

I once use them in scatter3D them like that,

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    ax1.scatter3D(
        df[i,0], 
        df[i,1],
        df[i,2],
        s = 2,
        marker='o',
        c = '#%02x%02x%02x' % tuple(val_rgb[i])
    )
```

However, in **scatter_matrix**, I find it only can add `c='red'` , Is there more accurate to adjust the color of each point?

PS(I also find adding color by label sns.pairplot(df), but also didn't find how to add color accurately...)

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset and image of what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a color using RGB format using a tuple of float values between 0 and 1. Thus simply divide the RGB values by 255:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 500
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(N, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
colors = np.random.randint(256, size=(N, 3))  # random colors


pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(data, alpha=.2, color=colors / 255)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want use rgb color in scatter_matrix, not scatter function

Comment: I have updated my answer which also applies to `plt.scatter`.